# Pluck properties from JSON into array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

**JSON User List**

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "jasondavis",
        "first_name": "Jason",
        "last_name": "Davis",
        "is_admin": "1",
        "gravatar": "31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144"
    },
    "1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad": {
        "id": "1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad",
        "name": "Jeff",
        "first_name": "Jeff",
        "last_name": "Mosley",
        "is_admin": "1",
        "gravatar": "5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e"
    }
}
```

**JS Array of Objects Format I need it in...**

From the above JSON I need just the `ID`, `Name`, and `gravatar` values in the format below.

Any help appreciated.

```
var userItemsArray = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'None',
        gravatar: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7ab1baf18a91ab4055923c5fd01d68a2?s=36&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG',
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jason Davis',
        gravatar: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7ab1baf18a91ab4055923c5fd01d68a2?s=36&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Item 2',
        gravatar: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/7988569?v=3&s=40',
    }
];
```

Comment: > 15k? what do you have so far?

Comment: Your question is not really a question. After 800+ questions you may have learned how to ask :-S

Comment: It's funny how you ignore comments and accept only "give me the codez" answers.

Comment: @zerkms chill out.  I'm still learning JavaScript it is new to me and I didn't know how to do this hence the reason for no demo code.  Hundreds of my questions have detailed demo code where I attempted different methods and thousands of comments discussing.

Comment: I was wondering how to do this myself.  Bookmarked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate over all keys and then map a new object with the wanted properties.

```js
var userList = {
        "1": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "jasondavis",
            "first_name": "Jason",
            "last_name": "Davis",
            "is_admin": "1",
            "gravatar": "31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144"
        },
        "1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad": {
            "id": "1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad",
            "name": "Jeff",
            "first_name": "Jeff",
            "last_name": "Mosley",
            "is_admin": "1",
            "gravatar": "5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e"
        }
    },
    userItemsArray = Object.keys(userList).map(function (k) {
        return {
            id: userList[k].id,
            name: userList[k].name,
            gravatar: userList[k].gravatar
        };
    });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(userItemsArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: OH! /me went for glasses. Sorry

Comment: Thanks this is perfect as my actual JSON Userlist doesn't map exactly to the property names that I need so I can see in your code how i'm able to map them to the correct ones in the new generated objects.  The other answer is kind of how I thought it might work in my head but it is down voted so i'm assuming there is something wrong with that method.  I like this though it's clean with the `map()`